# Suppose that A is a square matrix such that $A^2-3A-10E=0$. Show that A, A-4A are invertible

Tags: matrices

Suppose that A is a square matrix such that $A^2-3A-10E=0$. Show that $A,A-4A$ are invertible .

I understand that I should begin with 
$A^2-3A=10E$ 
$A(A-3)=10E$
$A(E-3)=10E$
$AE-3A=A(A-3)$ but what's next?

Comment: How did you go from the second line to the third line?

Comment: $\operatorname{rank}(A(A-3E))=n\leqslant\min\{\operatorname{rank}A,\operatorname{rank}(A-3E)\}$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote $E$?

Comment: Is $E$ the identity matrix? If so, then did you mean to write $A-4E$ instead of $A-4A$?

Comment: Have you learned about eigenvalues yet?

Answer (score 1):

As you have correctly shown, we have
$$
A(A - 3E) = 10E.
$$
It follows that
$$
A \frac{A - 3E}{10} = E.
$$
In other words, $\frac{A - 3E}{10}$ must be the inverse of $A$, so $A$ is invertible.

A similar approach can be taken for $B = A - 4E$. I recommend that you rewrite
$$
A^2 - 3A - 10E = 0 \implies (B + 4E)^2 - 3(B + 4E) - 10E = 0,
$$
then simplify and repeat the above process to show that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: Did you mean $A-3E$ where you wrote $A-E$?

Comment: where is 3 in $$A*A-E/10=E$$

Comment: @741147 See my latest edit

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, thanks for catching that